# BeautifulSoup - split scraped string in specific schema and save to dataframe

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get bold/italic string from below html code:

```
<div class="cmp-Review-author">
<span class="cmp-ReviewAuthor" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<meta itemprop="name" content="***TIER I ASSOCIATE PICKER/ PPQA ASSOCIATE***">
<a class="cmp-ReviewAuthor-link" rel="nofollow" href="/cmp/Amazon.com/reviews?fjobtitle=Order+Picker">TIER I ASSOCIATE PICKER/ PPQA ASSOCIATE</a> 
<!-- -->(***Former Employee***)<!-- --> - 
<a class="cmp-ReviewAuthor-link" rel="nofollow" href="/cmp/Amazon.com/reviews?fcountry=US&amp;floc=Edgerton%2C+KS">***Edgerton, KS***</a>
 - <!-- -->***March 5, 2020***</span></div>
```

and save them in separate columns in a dataframe.

I am able to get a string as

```
TIER I ASSOCIATE PICKER/ PPQA ASSOCIATE (Former Employee) - Edgerton, KS - March 5, 2020
```

but not sure how to split it as position, employee_status, location, date
since this structure is different for each position line: (see example)

1. Customer Service Associate (Former Employee) - Missouri City, TX - December 19, 2019
2. Picker, Processor, Gatekeeper, Ambassador, Problem Solver, Tier 3 Trainer (Former Employee) - Hebron, KY - March 6, 2020
3. Kurier (Current Employee) - Manheim - March 6, 2020
4. Picker/Packer (Former Employee) - North Randall, OH - March 5, 2020
5. Tdr (Current Employee) - 5300 holibird Avenue - March 5, 2020
   any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A regex (regular expression) seems like a good way to do what you're looking for. The pattern of the strings you posted seems to be:

`<position> (<employee status>) - <location> - date`

which you can turn into the following regular expression

`^(.*)\ \((.*)\)\ -\ (.*)\ -\ (.*)?`

Here's the full Python code:

```
import re

s = 'TIER I ASSOCIATE PICKER/ PPQA ASSOCIATE (Former Employee) - Edgerton, KS - March 5, 2020'
pattern = '^(.*)\ \((.*)\)\ -\ (.*)\ -\ (.*)?'

position, employee_status, location, date = re.match( pattern, s ).groups( )
```

[Here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) [are](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) [some](https://regex101.com/) [resources](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634) for learning about and using regular expressions.